# Html to retrieve all images (jpg, png) without mentioning the name of the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have following directory in web site

`http://localhost/uploads/`

i have over 20 images in the directory with several names. How to code html to retrieve all images (jpg, png) without mentioning the name of the image?

```
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="http://localhost/uploads" ></div>
```

Comment: You'll need to use a server-side language (PHP, ASP.NET etc).

Comment: @ca8msm can you post a simple php code here

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get from your server

Use :

```
var dir = "localhost/uploads/";
var fileextension = ".png";
$.ajax({
    //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
    url: dir,
    success: function (data) {
        //List all .png file names in the page
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http://", "");
            $("body").append("<img src='" + dir + filename + "'>");
        });
    }
});
```

If you have other extensions, you can make it an array and then go through that one by one using in_array().

P.s : The above source code is not tested in localhost. In a hosted website it is tested and works

Answer (score 1):

Try this you can get multiple image extension

```
$dirname = "your-image-dir-name/";
$images =  glob("{$dirname}*.png, {$dirname}*.jpeg, {$dirname}*.gif");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```